# Checking Working hours

Tags: javascript, html

I am banging my head to the wall trying to figure out why this code won't run. 
The function isWorkingHour is sure working because I am using it here: [Working Hours (Working Demo)](http://kiosk.0fees.net/wh2.htm)

Can anyone help.
Here is the JS code:

```
function makecall()
{

if (isWorkingHour(now)) {
    //it's in schedule
    window.alert("Office is open");
    }
    else {
    window.alert("Office is close");    
    }
}


function isWorkingHour(now) {
return now.getDay() <= 4 && now.getHours() >= 9 && now.getHours() < 17;
}
```

The HTML I am using is as follows:

```
<input type="button" id="CallButton" class="callButton" value="Call" onclick="makecall()" />
        <p id="demo">Click the button to check if now is working hours</p>
```

Here is the JSFiddle of what I am stuck with. [http://jsfiddle.net/zfSTj/3](http://jsfiddle.net/zfSTj/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `makecall` isn't a global function (it is wrapped in function that is called onload), so you can't access it from an intrinsic event attribute.

Second, you never define "now".

Start by defining `now`:

```
function makecall() {
    var now = new Date();
```

Then attach an event listener instead of using an `onclick` attribute:

```
document.getElementById('CallButton').addEventListener('click', makecall);
```

Such: http://jsfiddle.net/zfSTj/8/

Comment: When I tried adding the event listener on the function that is called on page load it didn't attached to the click event. I reverted back to the OnClick inline JS function call and simply added the 
var now = new Date();

Answer (score 1):

In the JSFiddle is pretty clear: the `now` variable is not defined. Replace `now` with `new Date()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
makecall = function() {

    if (isWorkingHour(new Date())) {
        //it's in schedule
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Office is open";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Office is closed";
    }
}
```

Do this to make `makecall` a global function so you can access it within JSFiddle.

I also went ahead and replaced `now` in your original parameter (which doesn't exist at the time of it being passed) with a `new Date()`